# Custom vectorizer transformer in sklearn with cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, cross-validation, pipelines

I created a custom transformer class called `Vectorizer()` that inherits from `sklearn`'s `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin` classes. The purpose of this class is to provide vectorizer-specific hyperparameters (e.g.: `ngram_range`, vectorizer type: `CountVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer`) for the `GridSearchCV` or `RandomizedSearchCV`, to avoid having to manually rewrite the pipeline every time we believe a vectorizer of a different type or settings could work better.

The custom transformer class looks like this:

```
class Vectorizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, vectorizer:Callable=CountVectorizer(), ngram_range:tuple=(1,1)) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.vectorizer = vectorizer
        self.ngram_range = ngram_range
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print(f">>> Vectorizer.fit() called with vectorizer={self.vectorizer} and ngram_range={self.ngram_range}.")
        return self 
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        print(f">>> Vectorizer.transform() called with vectorizer={self.vectorizer} and ngram_range={self.ngram_range}.")
        X_ = X.copy()
        X_vect_ = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(X_)  # problem is in this line! 
        X_vect_ = X_vect_.toarray()
        # print(X_vect_.shape)
        # print(self.vectorizer.vocabulary_)
        # time.sleep(5)
        return X_vect_
```

(Side note: `time.sleep(5)` was merely added to make debugging easier by preventing debug info overflowing on one another.)

I intend to use the custom vectorizer in the following way, with a pipeline and a hyperparameter tuning step:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('column_transformer', ColumnTransformer([
        ('ltype_encode', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), ['Type']),
        ('text_vectorizer', Vectorizer(), 'Text')],
        remainder='drop')
    ),
    ('model', LogisticRegression())
])

param_dict = {
    'column_transformer__text_vectorizer__vectorizer': [CountVectorizer(), TfidfVectorizer()]
}

randsearch = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_dict, cv=2, scoring='f1').fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now as I was debugging, I have a guess of the problem in my code: the above `GridSearchCV` uses a 2-fold cross validation. First, it takes half of the data to train the model and reserves the other half for evaluation. However, the `Vectorizer()` class's `transform()` method will try to call `fit_transform()` on the evaluation dataset again, even though when testing/evaluating, we would want to use the previously fit vectorizer without a refit.

Question is: how could I rectify this problem?

Imports:

```
import time
import pandas as pd 
from typing import Callable
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

and sample data in semicolon-separated format:

```
Src;Text;Type;Target
A99;hi i love python very much;c;1
B07;which programming language should i learn;b;0
A12;what is the difference between python django flask;b;1
A21;i want to be a programmer one day;c;0
B11;should i learn java or python;b;1
C01;how much can i earn as a programmer with python;a;0
c01;hello <FLAG> <FLAG> I m from france i enjoyed this lecture thank u very much HEAVY BLACK HEART HEAVY BLACK HEART HEAVY BLACK HEART HEAVY BLACK HEART;b;1
ssa;hi hola salut <FOREIGN> <FOREIGN> <FOREIGN> <FOREIGN> SMILING FACE WITH HALO HEAVY BLACK HEART CLINKING GLASSES <FLAG> <FLAG>;a;1
```

Comment: Would this not be solved by changing the method called from `fit_transform` to just `transform`?

Comment: @Oxbowerce no, because then `CountVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer` would never be fitted. It would lead to a `sklearn NotFittedError: Vocabulary not fitted or provided`.

Comment: Why not fit them during fit then?

Comment: As @BenReiniger mentioned, why then not simply fit the vectorizer within the `fit` method?

Comment: You are right guys, I indeed left that out. Such a stupid little mistake. Thanks a lot to both of you, it works now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by simply changing the method that is called within `transform` to the `transform` method of the vectorizer. In addition you would also have to add a call to `fit` within the `fit` method to make sure that the vectorizer is actually fitted before being used to transform any data:

```
class Vectorizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, vectorizer:Callable=CountVectorizer(), ngram_range:tuple=(1,1)) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.vectorizer = vectorizer
        self.ngram_range = ngram_range
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print(f">>> Vectorizer.fit() called with vectorizer={self.vectorizer} and ngram_range={self.ngram_range}.")
        self.vectorizer.fit(X)
        return self 
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        print(f">>> Vectorizer.transform() called with vectorizer={self.vectorizer} and ngram_range={self.ngram_range}.")
        X_ = X.copy()
        X_vect_ = self.vectorizer.transform(X_)
        X_vect_ = X_vect_.toarray()
        return X_vect_
```